# xss attack through iframe src

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

I am allowing users to embed a youtube or any other video source by only asking them to submit the `src` of the embed code they receive. Then I save it into the database and load it through an iframe. However,f there is a source, for instance, `src="http://innocent.com/hackingContent.php"`, then is my website vulenrable to an xss attack?

I am estimating that the user may have a malicious script in that `src` which will load as soon as the iframe embeds the source into my own html.

**EDIT** What if the src contains `<script type="text/javascript" src="evilScript.js"></script>` . Although I **am** using a `preg_match` just to make sure that its a url only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are vulnerable.  What's preventing a bad user from linking to porn?  Or a site that looks legit and harvests usernames and passwords.

Why don't you build a white list of video sources you will accept...validate submitted urls are on those domains and verify the url exists.

That way people can't insert completely random urls into your content.

A "white list" is a list of values that you will accept.  For example, on your server, when the user submits a url, you would accept anything from

http://www.youtube.com....

right?  So you make a list of all the urls you will accept, and then make sure the user's input matches an item from your list. If it doesn't you reject it.  (By match we mean 'begins with' or something like that -- obviously not an exact match)

A "Black list" would be the opposite.  You would have a list, but its a list of things you **won't allow**.

White List == **List of things you allow**
Black List == **List of things you don't allow**

Comment: You mean using the `curl` library for URL validation?

Comment: something like that.  You could also possibly download the content and process it on your server to make sure it's legit.

Comment: Speaking of which, when you say `white list of video source`, is that different from an iframe. How does that work? It would be helpful if you could explain it in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, if the iframe src is different than the domain that is invoking said iframe, you are protected from XSS attacks. This is per the **Same-domain Origin Policy**.

Comment: the iframe `src` can be `javascript:...` which will run in the context of the containing window.

Comment: Thanks so much David. So you are saying that if I am loading `http://innocent.com/hackingContent.php` through the iframe into `example.com/goodContent.php` then its not an issue right?

Comment: if he allows any url, someone could still have nefarious content displayed thru his site...right?

Comment: @Esailija That is specifically the problem I am trying to address. +1 for you

Comment: @jbloom1704 there are millions of ways to do xss if you don't validate the url at all.

Comment: @Esailija: The assumption here is that the URL is a valid URL. Also, my question is fundamentally correct. You are not XSS-vulnerable given the OP's situation.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco Yes, I followed that. I find this helpful as well. But the `javascript:...alert("you have been hacked")` is actually functional when it is stored and retrieved from the database. I santized it such that everytime anything goes in the databae it does not contain the word `javascript` or at least `javascript:` iff its also being loaded into iframe.